# Does Java Integer class have a compare method which returns Comparator?

Tags: java, comparator, method-reference

I was reading the Java [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html) and saw this line of code:

```
Comparator<Integer> normal = Integer::compare;
```

About the right hand side, I tried looking for documentation which explains how compare returns a Comparator for an Integer object. But I found none. The Java API [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare(int,%20int)) show the following:

```
public static int compare(int x, int y)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What makes you think `compare` returns a `Comparator`? How would that even work?

Comment: Integer::compare refers to the method as a lambda,which automatically coerces to comparable b/c comparable is one of the interfaces that supports coercion from a lambda.

Comment: I believe the term for interface which supports coercion from a lambda is functional interface

Comment: @JörgWMittag That code compiles fine, so this doesn't seem to be a useful complaint; it's more of a reiteration of the question.

Comment: `Integer::compare` is a _method reference_ which is one way to define an implementation of a _functional interface_. That method reference is equivalent to `(a, b) -> Integer.compare(a, b)`, which is a _lambda expression_.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, I was asking myself those exact questions and couldn't figure it out. So I had to ask.

Comment: @PiRocks, thank you for your answer. It helped make things clear.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: Exactly. If `compare` *did* return a `Comparator`, the code wouldn't compile. The fact that the code compiles means that `compare` *cannot possibly* return a `Comparator`. Also, the documentation clearly shows that `compare` does not return a `Comparator`. So, given that the documentation *clearly* shows that compare doesn't return a `Comparator`, and the fact that the code compiles *clearly* shows that compare *cannot possibly* return a `Comparator`, it would be interesting to know which documentation / tutorial / teacher told the OP that `compare` returns a `Comparator`.

Comment: … if only to contact the author of that documentation / tutorial and ask them to improve it, in order to avoid future programmers stumbling over the same hurdles as the OP.

Comment: @JörgWMittag - your initial response seems a little harsh.  I imagine the OP's thought process was that since 'something' on the RHS generated a value that was assignable to Comparator<>, then the 'compare' method was somehow 'returning' it.  We might know the method isn't even getting called, but the OP clearly doesn't, else he'd not have needed to ask the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Comparator<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) is a functional interface with the signature `int compare(T o1, T o2);`. From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) of *java.util.function*: "Functional interfaces provide target types for lambda expressions and method references."

The method `Integer#compare(int x, int y)` matches this signature. Its method reference can therefore be assigned to a variable of type `Comparator<Integer>`.

To better understand this, I suggest that you read about [lambda expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html), [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) and functional interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Integer class implements only `Comparable` interface.

The  `compare` method in  [Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java/lang/Integer.html#compare(int,%20int)) class is NOT `Comparator's` `compare` method Implementation. `compare` is a static helper method in Integer class itself.

Even before Java 8 we have `compare` method in `Integer` class. Integer class has two methods in this context one is

`public static compare(Integer val1,Integer val2)`

another

`public int compareTo(Integer val)`. //Comparable Interface Implementation

Therefore, If you invoke `compare` method of `Integer` class it internally still invoke the impmentation of `compareTo` Method of the `Comparable` interface defined in the Integer class as below.

```
public static int compare(int x, int y) {
 Integer.valueOf(x).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(y));  
}
```